# Wordpress Menu missing in Appearance bar

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to make custom WordPress theme from scratch so i deleted all my themes, and now the Menu is missing from appearance bar, 
i tried adding `add_theme_support( 'menus' );` code in `functions.php`  file then my page itself is not opening.

Attached is the screenshot for your reference.

pls help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to registered menu using [`register_nav_menus()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus) in [`after_setup_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) action hook.

Please check below code. it help you to create two type of menu display location

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'nepalbuzz' ),
            'footer'  => esc_html__( 'Footer Menu', 'nepalbuzz' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup' );
```

> This code goes to your custom theme `function.php` file

For display menu used [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function.

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
    $args = array(
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'menu_class'        => 'menu nepalbuzz-nav-menu',
        'container'         => false
    );
    wp_nav_menu( $args );
}
```

> This code goes to your custom theme file where you want to display menu

Comment: Thank you sooooo much this worked for me thanks again... Can you pls explain why "nepalbuzz" is for?

Comment: It's Text domain. Unique identifier for retrieving translated strings. `Default value: 'default'`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Please check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `functions.php`

```
register_nav_menus(
    array('header_menu' =>'This is Header Menu'));
```

to display this menu use this code where you want to display your menu

```
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'header_menu','container'=>''));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... even after adding code its still not working,

Answer (score 0):

Please use register_nav_menus()

So that you can create a custom Menu for your theme. Like

```
function register_theme_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
}
```

After that add the menu by "after_setup_theme" hook like

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_theme_menu' );
```

The full code is like in you fuctions.php file.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_theme_menu' );
function register_theme_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
}
```

get full info from https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu